# Default ErrorTemplate displays alongside with a custom ErrorTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a custom Validation.ErrorTemplate and for some reason, WPF displays both my custom error template and the default one. They both show the same error as expected, however I don't want to display the default ErrorTemplate.

My code:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="MyTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" Background="#11FF0000" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="errorBorder"/>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                    <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Right"
                               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=errorBorder}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.IsFocused, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Polygon  VerticalAlignment="Center" Points="0,4,4,4" Fill="red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="red"
                                  StrokeThickness="2" />
                            <Border Background="red" CornerRadius="0" Padding="4">
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="white" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                               Text="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And this

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyTextBox}"/>
```

I'd like to know if anyone knows why WPF displays both my error template and the default one.

EDIT
http://i58.tinypic.com/a14k6q.png - the picture with both errors showing

Comment: remove the Trigger `Validation.HasError` from your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you defined `ErrorTemplate` and also defiend a `Validation.HasError` trigger in your style, you could use one of them. If you want to use the `ErrorTemplate` you need to remove the trigger, and change the Text binding to `"Path=AdornedElement.Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent"` then you will just see the result from `ErrorTemplate`:

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border/>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                    <Popup>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Polygon/>
                            <Border>

             <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, 
                        Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent,
                        Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: @Timeless, please note you can use either of them to show the error message. Just don't apply both.